# How i can store javascript array object saved somehow so that I can use it later

Tags: javascript

I have a situation like follows:

I have a id select page where user can select id from the shown ids on the page.When the user select the id i store them as a comma seperated value in a hidden input field.

```
      <input type="hidden" values="234,678,987" />
```

I have a button which on clicking pops up a dialog box which then displays the selected ids. The ids here shown I take from the hidden field. 
Now I have a requirement to store the product id and name.So probably in this case what should i do because now i can't be able to save this datastructure in hidden input field. Even if i use javascript array ,how can i save that array and use it future for displaying.Is it possible to save array object in hidden input field ....and retrieve it later as array object again...?

Comment: are you going to different pages on your website?

Comment: yes..I am going to different pages.

Comment: I am not going to use cookie..

Comment: So what are you going to use? Sessions? authenticated users?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/cVxKx/4/).

If you want to store the object in an input field, you can use [`JSON.stringify()`](http://www.json.org/js.html):

```
 //Pass your array (or JSON object) into JSON.stringify:
 JSON.stringify([{id:1, product_id: 2, name: 'stack'},
                 {id: 2, product_id: 2, name: 'overflow'}] )
```

which will yield:

```
 "[{"id":1,"product_id":2,"name":"stack"},{"id":2,"product_id":2,"name":"overflow"}]"
```

You can store this value in a hidden field (or a data attribute):

```
 <input type="hidden" id="project" value="[{'id':1,'product_id':2,'name':'stack"',{'id':2,'product_id':2,'name':'overflow'}]" />
```

Obviously, you can combine these steps (or do it through PHP / Rails / ...)

```
 $('#project').val(JSON.stringify([1,2,3]));
```

You can then decode this using, for instance, jQuery:

```
 $.parseJSON($('#project').val());
```

This should allow you to use the process you are using, but store Javascript objects in your input fields.  Hope this helps!

Comment: well this seems quite good but can i stringify a array object directly or iterate over all the array and create a syntax like above and the stringify...also which library i have to include in jsp page for JSON.Stringify...

Comment: JSON.stringify is part of JavaScript now.  You'll be able to use it natively.  There are plenty of Javascript libraries for parsing JSON, jQuery has one, but there are tons of others.  Also, you can stringify an array, JSON will take care of this appropriate.  Take a look at this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ghayes/cVxKx/4/) for examples.

Comment: how i can create this format  [{id:1, product_id: 2, name: 'stack'},
             { id: 2, product_id: 2, name: 'overflow' }];

Comment: From JSP?  Maybe [this](http://www.roseindia.net/tutorials/json/json-jsp-example.shtml) will help.  Just look up 'JSP JSON' and there's a ton of material on the subject.

Comment: no i mean just in javascript like if i have

Comment: var my_cars= new Array()
my_cars["cool"]="Mustang";
my_cars["family"]="Station Wagon";
my_cars["big"]="SUV";

Comment: so i just need to do JSON.stringify(my_cars) right...

Comment: Yup, that should work.  Use `console.log(my_cars);` `console.log(JSON.stringify(my_cars));` and you'll be able to see it in action.

Comment: got here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json...thanks

Comment: Why are you using an associative array as opposed to a JSON object?  E.g. my_cars = []; my_cars.push({cool: "Mustang"}); my_cars.push({family: "Station Wagon"});  console.log(my_cars); console.log(JSON.stringify(my_cars));

Answer (score 4):

You can

1. store the value in memory, using JS

   ```
   var arr = [];
   arr.push(your_value);
   ```
2. keep creating new attribute/values in the dom using JS
3. pass the value from page to page through the query string
4. store the value in a cookie to be retrieved again
5. store the value on the server (in a file/db) to retrieve again

---

***Note:**

Options 3 and 5 are only meaningful if you want to go to another page (on the site).

Options 4 and 5 are good if you want to close the browser and retrieve that info at a later point.*

Comment: well i am interested in storing the value in memory..

Comment: tell me more about storing in memory..

Comment: There is nothing more to tell, when you create a javascript array it is stored in memory. It will only be destroyed if it is created within a function, or you go to a different page. In which case you might look at sending the array to the server for handling.

Comment: so u r telling me to create some kind of global javascript array...

Comment: user882196, yes.  If you only need that information while viewing the page, then yes, using a global variable (example number 1) is all you need. `.push()` adds a value to the end of the array and `.pop()` retrieves the values from the end of the array (`.shift()` and `.unshift()` work from the front of the array).

Comment: One more option - localStorage.

Comment: @andrey.shedko you're correct.  This answer was from 2011, when websql, indexdb and localstorage were all competing for adoption. Localstorage seems to have won

Comment: Local storage and browser cookies (perhaps HTTP cookies — though I wouldn't recommend) are also plausible options.

Answer (score 4):

If you are not worried about IE7, you can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/dom/storage):

```
window.localStorage.setItem('myArray', JSON.stringify([234,678,987]));
// retrieve
var myArray = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem('myArray'));
```

The JSON is supported by modern browsers. You can add it by including [json2](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js).

Comment: without knowing what platform/framework he is using on the server (if any) this would be the best option

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about preserving the data after a new page has loaded.  You can use your current approach of storing the data as a string in a hidden input, and then *parse* that string into a JavaScript object later.  Another option is that your server-side code can produce some inline JavaScript declaring the JavaScript object you need.  If you're using ASP.NET, for example, your page could have something like this:

```
// Assuming "serverSideIds" is declared as a List<string>

<% var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer(); %>
var ids = <%= serializer.Serialize(serverSideIds) %>;
```