# How to convert javascript associative array to json and use later using parseJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, associative-array

Look I want to do this:

```
function MyObject()
{
  this.attr1;
  this.attr2;
  this.attr3;
}

var myArray = new Array();
myArray["a"] = new MyObject();
myArray["b"] = new MyObject();
myArray["c"] = new MyObject();

var json_myArray = CONVERT_TO_JSON( myArray ); // Or stringify
```

Finally:

```
var myOriginalArray = $.parseJSON( json_myArray );
```

The myOriginalArray and myArray will be identical, including the keys (myOriginalArray["a"])

Comment: To problems: (a) Arrays should only have numerical indexes, `JSON.stringify` won't consider any other properties. See [JavaScript associative array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json). (b) With this simple object, serialization and deserialization will work as expected, but if you add methods to the functions prototype, things get more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

```
JSON.stringify()
```

and

```
JSON.parse()
```

Comment: He is using `$.parseJSON` and `$.getJSON`.

Comment: @Derek I'm not sure what your point is. He wants to encode and parse JSON. jQuery is a redundant tool for this (and it can't encode).

Comment: IE8 and lower do not support JSON encoding (and jQuery can encode JSON).