# How can I stringify a Javascript array to store in localStorage

Tags: javascript, json, local-storage

I am trying to store an array in localStorage (HTML5) which needs to be a string, but enable direct access to objects I store in the array by defining the index.  When I try to JSON.stringify I just get [] which doesn't store the array of objects in localStorage.

```
var mylist = [];

mylist["mykey1"] = {id: "1", title: "First"};
mylist["mykey2"] = {id: "2", title: "Second"};

localStorage.setItem("mylist", JSON.stringify(mylist));  // stores [] only - uggh!

var mylist2 = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("mylist"));

document.write(JSON.stringify(mylist2["mykey1"])); // want it to display:  {"id": "1", "title": "First"}
```

Comment: That's not a list, it's an associative array.

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript associative array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json) -- same problem.

Comment: Thanks.  I solved below after trying object declaration instead of array.  Posted answer.  Doh!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I solved it just by changing the mylist var from [] array to {} object.

```
var mylist = {};
```

Answer (score 1):

You've created an **array** and you're trying to use it like an **associative array** or **map**

What's actually happening is when you type

```
mylist["mykey1"] = {id: "1", title: "First"}
```

It's trying to get a *list element* at index **"mykey1"**, which *is being ignored by the JSON parser*. This is probably due to the fact that it cannot determine an integer index into your list for `mykey1`, or it's conversion to a number is too large.

You'll notice that if you do this:

```
mylist[1] = {id: "1", title: "First"}
```

Your JSON string will be `"[null,{id: "1", title: "First"}]"`, as you haven't specified a `0th index` element, but you have set the `1st index` element.

Comment: Well, that's not completely true (or I misunderstood). `mylist` will have a property `mykey1` with that value, but it will be ignored by `JSON.stringify`.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are using an array as a normal object.

Change `var mylist = [];` to `var mylist = {};`, then thing will be work.

***[Check the demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4neBZ/)***.