# dynamically create two dimensional table with string indexes in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array

I need to parse a table to JSON, I found this solution and it works:

```
    var tab=[{"value":"1.0","label":"Alabama"},{"value":"2.0","label":"Alaska"},        {"value":"3.0","label":"American Samoa"}];
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(tab);  
    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(myJsonString);
```

The problem is when I declare dynamically the two dimensional table 'tab' it doesn't work:

```
    var tab_desc1= new Array(3);
    tab_desc1[0]=new Array(2);
    tab_desc1[0]["value"]="1.0";
    tab_desc1[0]["label"]="Alabama";
    tab_desc1[1]=new Array(2);
    tab_desc1[1]["value"]="2.0";
    tab_desc1[1]["label"]="Alaska";
    tab_desc1[2]=new Array(2);
    tab_desc1[2]["value"]="3.0";
    tab_desc1[2]["label"]="American Samoa";
    var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(tab_desc1);    
    var jsonData = $.parseJSON(myJsonString);
```

Logically my declaration contains error, bur I can't see it.
Any help! Thanks.

Comment: Your inner dimension is _not_ an array, so don't do `tab_desc1[0] = new Array()`.  It is an _object_ (JS arrays do not have string keys) so create it as one `tab_desc1[0] = {}`

Comment: You are using arrays with strings. If you want to use strings use object. In your case you should use array and objects together.

Comment: i'm working a mobile application (jquery mobile and phoneGap), I need it for an auto complete search with complex object: http://www.andymatthews.net/code/autocomplete/local_complex.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [JavaScript associative array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json)

Comment: "stringify()" to convert the array to json string ( I included a library script to use this method) and it works well in the case of the first delcatation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
tab_desc1[0] = new Array(2);
```

Should be

```
tab_desc1[0] = {};
```

And same with others.

But I don't know the purpose of stringify a variable to string and then parse it back.

Comment: this is the answer, congratulation !

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that arrays and objects are not the same thing.

Your first code creates an array of *objects*.

Your second code creates an array of *arrays*, but then sets non-numeric properties on those arrays. JS arrays are a type of object so it is not an error to set non-numeric properties, but `stringify()` will only include the numeric properties. You need to do this:

```
var tab_desc1 = []; // Note that [] is "nicer" than new Array(3)
tab_desc1[0] = {};  // NOTE the curly brackets to create an object not an array
tab_desc1[0]["value"] = "1.0";
tab_desc1[0]["label"] = "Alabama";
tab_desc1[1] = {};  // curly brackets
tab_desc1[1]["value"] = "2.0";
tab_desc1[1]["label"] = "Alaska";
tab_desc1[2] = {};  // curly brackets
tab_desc1[2]["value"] = "3.0";
tab_desc1[2]["label"] = "American Samoa";

var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(tab_desc1);    
var jsonData = $.parseJSON(myJsonString);
```

You could also do this:

```
var tab_desc1 = [];
tab_desc1[0] = {"value":"1.0","label":"Alabama"};
tab_desc1[1] = {"value":"2.0","label":"Alaska"};
tab_desc1[2] = {"value":"3.0","label":"American Samoa"};
```

(Also, why stringify and then immediately parse to get back the same object?)

Comment: because I read data from a file , I should browse it to insert data in the array and then parse it to JSON ( cause the script requires json format )