# Submitting multiple values for one input field

Tags: javascript, jquery

**What I'm trying to do:**

I'm trying to build a very simple visual layout builder. 
The idea is that, the user selects a block, and it has some settings in it, those setting values are stored in the hidden input, and when the user saves the page, i store those values in the database.

**Basic block is ok:**

For example, user selects a 'text' block, it is added like this:

```
<div>
    <input type="hidden" value="text" name="item_name[]">
    <input type="hidden" value="" name="item_title[]">
    <input type="hidden" value="sdsd" name="item_text[]">
</div>
```

**Problem:**

However, some of the blocks have more than one values for each field. For example, 'gallery' block, which has multiple image urls, image titles etc. I'm facing problem in finding a suitable way to put together the multiple values and submit.

Right now I'm adding them to a string with jQuery, separated with __. I can store the data and separate it, but the problem is that if I want to remove any image from it, it is very difficult because I have just added them in the string, so its hard to find it and remove it.

```
<div>
text item
<input type="hidden" value="gallery" name="item_name[]">
<input type="hidden" value="__http://img1.jpg__http://img2.jpg" name="img_path[]">
<input type="hidden" value="__img1__img2" name="img_title[]">
<input type="hidden" value="" name="img_desc[]"></input>
</div>
```

**Question:**

What would be the suitable way to send multiple values for the above block example, keeping in the mind that there will be multiple blocks having multiple input values?

Thanks.

Comment: It shouldn't be too hard to remove one, you can use `.split()` in jQuery to turn it into an array then `.splice()` to remove the one you want?

Comment: Store those settings in an Array instead of hidden inputs? Where is your jQuery?

Comment: @anOG - I think he is attempting to persist data across pages somehow.

Answer (score 1):

1. Build a [Javascript Array](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_array.asp) with all values.
2. Convert the [array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json)
3. Submit JSON as the value of the hidden field
4. On server side, use PHP [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) function to convert JSON to PHP object or array