# Cannot serialize javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, serialization

I have an associative array which looks something like this (not actual code):

```
sort_order['14682007'][0] = "1"
sort_order['14682007'][1] = "0"
sort_order['82501220'][0] = "2"
sort_order['82501220'][1] = "1"
sort_order['82501220'][2] = "0"
```

I'd like to serialize this array this way:

```
sort_order = JSON.stringify(sort_order);
```

But it returns only an empty string. Colud some one help me?

Comment: how should your expected output looks?

Comment: How did you create `sort_order`? How did you create the individual entries in `sort_order`?

Comment: Are you sure `sort_order` is constructed properly? Look at `console.log(sort_order)`. BTW, don't use the same variable for the input and output, it's confusing.

Comment: Without knowing what `sort_order` is exactly, we can only guess, which is likely wasting our time and not helpful to you.

Comment: Duplicate of [JavaScript associative array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4425289/218196) maybe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you declare your variables properly, an example:

```
    var sort_order = {};
    sort_order['82501220'] = [];
    sort_order['14682007'] = [];
    sort_order['14682007'][0] = "1";
    sort_order['14682007'][1] = "0";
    sort_order['82501220'][0] = "2";
    sort_order['82501220'][1] = "1";
    sort_order['82501220'][2] = "0";

    console.log(JSON.stringify(sort_order));
```

Note: If you declare sort_order as an array in this case you will have a very long sparse array I think.

Comment: I totally agree with this answer. I just recreated this example with `sort_order = [];`. At last when I did `JSON.stringify(sort_order);` the browser memory increases and crashes since it is a very huge sparse array. +1 for the brilliant (and very important) input