# JavaScript - Why can I set keys in an Array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, associative-array

I thought I knew JavaScript pretty decently, until I encountered other developer's code which knocked me down:

```
var data = [];
```

As you can see by its name, it's supposed to be used as an associative array (i.e. `Object`), but it is an `Array`. And then he assigns values to keys of that array:

```
data['somekey'] = 'somevalue';
```

I thought that wasn't possible in JavaScript, I thought it would throw an exception, but it works. Why does it work? Why do we need Objects then, if we can use Arrays instead? Is it considered a bad practice, and should I shame that developer?

Comment: Try this: `typeof [];`

Comment: _"should I put that developer to shame?"_: do not do this.

Comment: `Array` instances are Objects so you can set properties on them. But the properties you set do not get iterated over by normal means (`for of` loop, `Array.prototype.forEach`, etc) unless they are positive integer keys

Comment: Everything is an object in javascript. The same way you can call an index from object using this sintaxe obj['item']

Comment: Somewhat related: [JavaScript associative array to JSON](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4425289/218196)

Comment: http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20data%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Adata%5B'pickles'%5D%20%3D%20%22loves%20'em%22%3B%0D%0Aalert(JSON.stringify(data.pickles))%3B%20

Answer (score 5):

It works because Arrays are just a special case of Objects. In fact, check this out:

```
typeof []; // "object"
```

Arrays give developers additional methods such as push, pop, etc. and allows the internal engines to better optimize them based on the way they are used.

In general, it's better to use a normal object for associative arrays since that's essentially what objects are. There's no real reason to use arrays as "associative arrays" in that case. Likewise, JS engines generally optimize objects into a hashmap-like structure which may or may not happen if you try and use a normal array in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

Almost all objects in javascript are derived from a hash object in some way or another. It's through this hash that objects like arrays, store their own internal properties and also allow them to be extended and overridden.

For instance, all of the following evaluate to "object":

```
typeof(null)
typeof([])
typeof({})
typeof(function(){}.prototype)
typeof(new function(){})
```

Comment: Well, `typeof null` only returns "object" because the algorithm says "if the value is null, return 'object'".

Answer (score 0):

Internally, JavaScript has only objects (and primitive types). Objects are unordered collection of key:value pairs, where key is string and value can be any JavaScript type.

Arrays, though on the outside look like normal arrays of any other language, are actually a special case of objects, with natively supported language syntax.

```
>typeof []
 "object" 

>Object.prototype.toString.call([]) 
"[object Array]"
```

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are Objects with some added abilities made specifically to make it easier to use numeric keys in a list-like fashion. So yes, you can assign properties to them like a normal object as well. Those abilities are retained.

As for why you need objects then...because without objects there wouldn't **be** javascript. Most things in JS are Objects. That's precisely what you're figuring out by noticing you can treat Arrays like Objects. *It's a bit backwards to conclude from that that Objects aren't needed when what you're discovering is that they are the base of most things in JS!*

Answer (score 0):

In **JavaScript** everything is really just key value pairs, take a look @ [this](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=var%20data%20%3D%20%5B%5D%3B%0D%0Adata%5B'pickles'%5D%20%3D%20%22loves%20'em%22%3B%0D%0Aalert(%22pickles%3A%20%22%20%2B%20data.pickles%20%2B%20%22%20because%20%5B%5D%20is%20an%20%22%20%2B%20typeof%20%5B%5D)%3B%20) -- where I threw together a quick example and hit the <kbd>Run</kbd> button towards the upper-right hand corner.

Answer (score -1):

As everybody knows everything in JS are objects which are key : value pairs.
Arrays are also objects internally.

```
var arr = ["this","is","array"];
```

when define this in JS, Internally it will be defined like an object with key as index.

```
arr = {0 : "this", 1 : "is", 2 : "array"}.
```

Also Array is a class which is wrapped over Object class and it has additional methods to access the values.

hope this helps you.

Comment: "everything in JS are objects which are key : value pairs" : no. Some values aren't objects. And no, internally arrays aren't wrapper over objects (not in any of the common JS engines).

Comment: If we check the prototype chain then the final class from which it will be inherited from will be Object class. Isn't that true.
var aa = []; aa.__proto__.__proto__ = Object class??
"Some values aren't objects" -> can you please elaborate little on this?

Comment: "3" and NaN are JS values but not objects. As for the internals, any JS engine use optimized arrays for dense arrays (and some of them even use typed arrays like arrays of short integers when the optimization is possible).