# Why does JSON.stringify() not work on this array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have an array which is declared like this:

```
array = [];
```

and has values as shown below -

```
....
ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc:"ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc"
ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4:"ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4"
....
```

These values are printed when I do console.log(array);

When I try to do a JSON.stringify(array), it does not seem to work. I want to store this array in localStorage using localStorage.setItem().

I tried an example like in this in the browser console:

```
var arr=[]
arr[0] = 1
arr[1] = 2
JSON.stringify(arr);
```

And the above example worked perfectly fine.

Please provide your inputs, I have been stuck at this for hours.

Comment: Please add json for which you are getting error

Comment: Step 1: Learn the difference between arrays and objects. There is no such thing as an associative array in JavaScript. You added arbitrary custom properties to an array, but those are not _elements_ of the array, so they don’t get serialized by JSON.stringify.

Comment: Both Objects and Arrays are associative, only that they keys are permitted to only be or be convertible to Strings and Numbers respectively.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript associative array to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to assign values in array like objects ; index can only be o,1,2 etc. not the strings like you have used. If you must do this, create an array of objects

Answer (score 1):

the problem is that you are trying to set the array index as strings `'ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc'` and `'ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4'` and although the browser seems to print it in the console, but array considers only **integer keys as valid indices**, so if you try to print `array.length`, it will print `0` and hence operations such as `JSON.stringify(array)` don't return you anything

```js
var array = [];
array['ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc'] = "ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc";
array['ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4'] = "ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4";
console.log(array);
console.log(array.length)
```

What you need is not an array but an object

```js
var obj = {};
obj['ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc'] = "ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc";
obj['ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4'] = "ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4";
console.log(obj);
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj))
```

Answer (score 0):

That's not an array, but an object. Objects don't stringify as well as arrays do.

Basically:

```
String = 'This is a string'

Array = [
  'This is a string',
  'And so is this'
]

Object = {
  firstString  : 'This is a string',
  secondString : 'And so is this.'
}
```

Comment: Both do fine, but only if their contents stringify.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in [a plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rFo33WKX8qsjEdP5Eu0t).

```
let array = [];
array.push({"ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc":"ChIJOaegwbTHwoARg7zN_9nq5Uc"});
array.push({"ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4":"ChIJXTwCdefHwoAR9Jr4-le12q4"});
console.log(JSON.stringify(array));
```

If you do a `console.log(array)`, you should see something like this:
[image]