# How to create JavaScript array from returned JSON value

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, servlets

I need a JavaScript variable in the form:

```
var myColumns = [{
                name       : "Name",
                type       : "string",
                visible    : true,
                filterType : "search",
                width      : 200
            },
            {...}
            ]
```

As per [this Dynamic Table](https://github.com/key-lime-box/dynamic-table) JavaScript spreadsheet API.

As part of an AJAX call I am making, I am returning a JSON of the form:

```
{
"columnData": "data as per var myColumns above",
"cellData": {
    "cell1": "value1",
    "cell2": "value2"
}
}
```

My issue is that when I get "columnData" from the JSON that the ajax call has returned and set it as a variable, JavaScript interprets it as a string, not an array.

```
var myColumns = result.columnData;
var myData = result.cellData;
```

However, if I were to define a new variable and copy paste the contents of the "columnData", JavaScript sees this as an array (rightly so, and the behaviour I was expecting).

So how to I formulate my JSON in such a way that I can extract an array from it, to satisfy the column definition?

You may be saying to yourself, "just set the column definition as a JSON and parse it". However I need to pass some functions in the column definition so I cannot do that in JSON (if my understanding is correct).

Edit:
The reason I want columnData to be an array of definitions is because I want to be able to return something like this:

```
[{
                     name       : "Configuration ID",
                     type       : "string",
                     visible    : true,
                     filterType : "search",
                     width      : 70,
                     field      : "configuration_id"
                     editor     : editableText
}]
```

Where editableText is a JavaScript variable:

```
var editableText = $("<div/>").dynamicTableEditor({
    editHandler: function(aData, aContext) {
       $("#save-data").html("Saving note: <strong>" + aData + "</strong>"); 
       executeAsync();
    }
 });
```

And so if I do:

```
var columnDefinition = results.columnData
console.log(columnsDefinition);
```

The output would be:

```
[{
                     name       : "Configuration ID",
                     type       : "string",
                     visible    : true,
                     filterType : "search",
                     width      : 70,
                     field      : "configuration_id"
                     editor     : editableText = $("<div/>").dynamicTableEditor({
    editHandler: function(aData, aContext) {
       $("#save-data").html("Saving note: <strong>" + aData + "</strong>"); 
       executeAsync();
    }
 })
}]
```

Comment: I don't think it's clear what problem is preventing you from just setting `columnData: JSON.parse(string)`

Comment: Because the string is not a JSON so there would be some parse error presumably. And its not a JSON because I want to be able to pass functions in it.

Comment: You can't pass functions in json and you need the json for the ajax. Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but what about something like `var myColumns = result.columnData.split(' ');` ? Makes an array split by the space delimiter. Unless the issue is that not all elements in the array are to be strings...

Comment: @IsaacAbramowitz Exactly. Some elements are boolean, other strings. Also see my edit. I am trying to pass a variable name. Is this possible?

Comment: hmm I'm not sure, maybe an associative array? Not sure if that can be converted to JSON though

Comment: See this question for details of associative arrays in JSON: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425289/javascript-associative-array-to-json